# Connect two nested graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

Is there an easy way I can connect the vertices of these graphs using the code I have? In other words, I want to connect the first node of the smaller decagon with the first node of the larger decagon, the second node of the smaller decagon with the second node of the larger decagon, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, calc}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black,draw,minimum size=.2cm,inner sep=0pt},}
    \tikzset{mynode/.style={circle, radius=.25pt, draw=darkgray, fill=white}}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[draw, minimum size=2cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10] (epta) {};
                \foreach \x in {1,2,...,10}{%
                \node[mynode] at (epta.corner \x) (e\x) [fill=black,scale=0.5] {};}
                
                \node[draw, minimum size=4cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10] (epta) {};
                \foreach \y in {1,2,...,10} {%
                \node[mynode] at (epta.corner \y) (e\y) [fill=black,scale=0.5] {};}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: straight from the manual -- use graphs and sub-graphs

Comment: It think you display name will be changed by the site owner soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your own tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, calc}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black,draw,minimum size=.2cm,inner sep=0pt},}
    \tikzset{mynode/.style={circle, radius=.25pt, draw=darkgray, fill=white}}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[draw, minimum size=2cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10] (epta) {};
                \foreach \x in {1,2,...,10}{%
                \node[mynode] at (epta.corner \x) (e\x) [fill=black,scale=0.5] {};}
                
                \node[draw, minimum size=4cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10] (epta) {};
                \foreach \y in {1,2,...,10} {%
                \node[mynode] at (epta.corner \y) (e\y) [fill=black,scale=0.5] {};}
                \foreach \a in {1,...,10}
                  \draw (36*\a:1) -- (36*\a:2);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Or, another short version:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={fill,inner sep=2pt,circle}]
\foreach \a [count=\b from 0] in {1,...,10} {
  \draw (36*\a:1) node [dot]{} -- (36*\a:2) node[dot]{};
  \draw (36*\a:1) -- (36*\b:1) (36*\a:2) -- (36*\b:2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Or, an even shorter version from the manual as pointed out by @jsbibra:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [nodes={fill, circle}, clockwise, radius=1cm, empty nodes, n=10] {
subgraph C_n [name=inner] -- subgraph C_n [name=outer]
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\def\N{10}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showpoints,dotscale=2,linecolor=red,plotpoints=\numexpr\N+1\relax](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \curvepnodes{0}{360}{4 t PtoC}{A}
    \curvepnodes{0}{360}{2 t PtoC}{B}
    \psnpolygon(0,\numexpr\N-1){A}
    \psnpolygon(0,\numexpr\N-1){B}
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,\N}{\psline(A\i)(B\i)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Animated Version

Only for dynamic people who like seeing moving objects.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\def\N{10}
\begin{document}
\foreach \r in {0.5,1.5,...,3.5}{
\begin{pspicture}[showpoints,dotscale=2,linecolor=red,plotpoints=\numexpr\N+1\relax](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \curvepnodes{0}{360}{4 t PtoC}{A}
    \curvepnodes{0}{360}{\r\space t PtoC}{B}
    \psnpolygon(0,\numexpr\N-1){A}
    \psnpolygon(0,\numexpr\N-1){B}
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,\N}{\psline(A\i)(B\i)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple, short code with using `graph` and `graph.standard` TikZ libraries:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,
                 graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [nodes={fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt}, 
        clockwise, radius=1cm, empty nodes, n=8]
           {
            subgraph C_n [name=inner] -- 
            subgraph C_n [name=outer]
            };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]